# Script moves object in wrong place

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have a script which replaces object on his destroyed prefab and calls them position and rotation (with some random). It perfectly works with a single object, but if I add another object with this script, it spawns "whackedPrefab" on the position of the first object.

Code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class whackReplacer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject whackPrefab;
    private float[] rotateVectors = { 0f, 90f, 180f}; 
    private float randomVector;
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Destroyer"){
            
            Debug.Log("I collided with: "+collision.gameObject.name);
            Instantiate(whackPrefab);           
            whackPrefab.transform.position = new Vector3(this.gameObject.transform.position.x,this.gameObject.transform.position.y,this.gameObject.transform.position.z);
            randomVector = rotateVectors[Random.Range(0, rotateVectors.Length)];
            whackPrefab.transform.rotation = new Quaternion(0f,this.gameObject.transform.rotation.x, randomVector+this.gameObject.transform.rotation.y,this.gameObject.transform.rotation.z);
            Destroy(gameObject);            
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easily fixed by using Instantiate(Object original, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation);

And this is solution:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class whackReplacer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject whackPrefab;
    private float[] rotateVectors = { 0f, 90f, 180f}; 
    private float randomVector;
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Destroyer"){           
            Debug.Log("I collided with: "+collision.gameObject.name);
            randomVector = rotateVectors[Random.Range(0, rotateVectors.Length)];
            Instantiate(whackPrefab, new Vector3(this.gameObject.transform.position.x,this.gameObject.transform.position.y,this.gameObject.transform.position.z), new Quaternion(0f,this.gameObject.transform.rotation.x, randomVector+this.gameObject.transform.rotation.y,this.gameObject.transform.rotation.z));         
            Destroy(gameObject);            
    }
    }
}
```